# Create Custom Big Notifications

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

I wanted to create a Notification including some controls. Since text and controls are small with default notification size (64dp), i wanted have it larger than default size.
It is possible to create larger notifications, and I think it is possible to have a custom layout, too, but I don't know how.

To be more specific, the following screenshot shows the notification from spotify (image take from [here](http://androidauthority.com/spotify-android-notifications-controls-233010/)): [image: Spotify notification]

As you can see, the size is bigger than default. Further, it has some kind of ImageButtons without text - if you use [*Notification.Builder.addAction()*](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), you may provide an icon but also need to provide a CharSequence as a description - if you leave the description empty, there will still be space reserved for the text and if you pass *null*, it will crash.

Can anybody tell me how to create a big notification with a custom layout?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create custom notification, android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168553/create-custom-notification-android)

Comment: @phemt.latd The answers given in that question deal with custom notification default size or default notification big size. I could not manage to have a custom notification big size with the given answers.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Update due to API changes:**

From API 24 on, the `Notification.Builder` contains a [setCustomBigContentView(RemoteViews)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setCustomBigContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews))-method. Also the [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) (which is part of the support.v4 package) contains this method.
Please note, that the documentation for the [NotificationCompat.Builder.setCustomBigContentView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setCustomBigContentView(android.widget.RemoteViews)) states:

> Supply custom RemoteViews to use instead of the platform template in the expanded form. This will override the expanded layout that would otherwise be constructed by this Builder object. No-op on versions prior to JELLY_BEAN.

Therefore, this will also only work for API >= 16 (JELLY_BEAN).

---

**Original Answer**

So after excessive google usage, I found [this tutorial](http://codeversed.com/expandable-notifications-android/) explaining how to use custom big layouts. The trick is not to use `setStyle()` but manually set the `bigContentView` field of the `Notification` **after building it**. Seems a bit hacky, but this is what I finally came up with:

notification_layout_big.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" <!-- This is where I manually define the height -->
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- some more elements.. --> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Building `Notification` in code:

```
Notification foregroundNote;

RemoteViews bigView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
    R.layout.notification_layout_big);

// bigView.setOnClickPendingIntent() etc..

Notification.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
foregroundNote = mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle("some string")
        .setContentText("Slide down on note to expand")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify_white)
        .setLargeIcon(bigIcon)
        .build();

foregroundNote.bigContentView = bigView;

// now show notification..
NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotifyManager.notify(1, foregroundNote);
```

**Edit**
As noted by chx101, this only works for API >= 16. I did not mention it in this answer, yet it was mentioned in the given linked tutorial above:

> Expanded notifications were first introduced in Android 4.1 JellyBean [API 16].

Comment: thank you.but if another notification come ,this notification's view back to the default view ,can you say why?

Comment: This is because Android OS wants to ensure all Notifications stay visible. You can increase the priority of the Notification using the [setPriority-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setPriority%28int%29). But you can never be sure, that your Notification is enlarged. Additionally, the user can always enlarge the Notification manually by sliding down on the Notification.

Comment: Doens't work for API level 8. `Field requires API level 16 (current min is 8): android.app.Notification#bigContentView`

Comment: what to do with lower version

Comment: @HRaval AFAIK it is not possible to do have a large custom notifiaction for lower API version. But you could check the API version on runtime with the help of the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423754/retrieving-android-api-version-programmatically)

Comment: @MalaKa thanx for replay...i have changed my minsdk to 16 but steel i cant see full notification...if my text is large then bottom part is hidden...any suggestion

Comment: @HRaval This sounds like you should open a question. Without more information it's very hard to tell.

Comment: @MalaKa please see my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804361/custom-notification-not-fully-visible

Comment: @MalaKa Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

[image]**Using Kotlin make custom notification**
             dialog_custom_notification

```
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp_10"
                        android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_main_notification"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="@dimen/dp_10">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ivAppIcon"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_36"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_36"
                                android:layout_gravity="top"
                                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_10"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvNotificationTitle"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Notification Tile"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvNotificationDescription"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
                                android:text="Notification Description" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="top">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvDateTime"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_gravity="top"
                                android:text="09:50" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

        shape_bg_main_notification
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />

            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp_6" />

        </shape>



        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
                    fun showOfflineNotification(context: Context, title: String, description: String) {
                        val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.myapp"
                        val intent = Intent(context, HomeActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("notification", 1)
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                        if (intent != null) {
                            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                context, getTwoDigitRandomNo(), intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
                            )
                            val defaultSoundUri =
                                RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

                            val remoteCollapsedViews = RemoteViews(packageName, R.layout.dialog_custom_notification)
                            remoteCollapsedViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNotificationTitle, title)
                            remoteCollapsedViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNotificationDescription, description)
                            remoteCollapsedViews.setTextViewText(R.id.tvDateTime, getTime())

                            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            notificationBuilder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteCollapsedViews)
                            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(
                                BitmapFactory.de

        codeResource(
                                        context.resources,
                                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher
                                    )
                                )
                                notificationBuilder.setBadgeIconType(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                                notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title)
                                if (description != null) {
                                    notificationBuilder.setContentText(description)
                                    notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                                        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(description)
                                    )
                                }
                                notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                                notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                                notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                                notificationBuilder.setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000))
                                notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

                                val notificationManager =
                                    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                                    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX
                                    val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                                        NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                                        "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME",
                                        importance
                                    )
                                    notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
                                    notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
                                    notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
                                    notificationChannel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(1000, 1000)
                                    assert(notificationManager != null)
                                    notificationBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
                                }
                                notificationManager.notify(
                                    getTwoDigitRandomNo()/*Id of Notification*/,
                                    notificationBuilder.build()
                                )
                            }
                        }

                        private fun getTime(): String {
                            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                            val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
                            val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
                            return strDate
                        }

                        fun getTwoDigitRandomNo(): Int {
                            return Random().nextInt(90) + 10
                        }



      [1]: https://me.stack.imgur.com/rQFP8.png


  [1]: https://me.stack.imgur.com/fKM9C.png
```

Comment: Kotlin big custom notification