# Custom Notification Bug in showing it's view

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, custom-view

I try to create custom notification according  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283668/3553815)  answer.
Everything was working ok and custom view show until anther notification from device come up and mine go to the second row. Then suddenly my notification's view is back to the default view.

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367631/change-notification-layout

Comment: What do you mean by *suddenly my notification's view back to the default view*? You lose the layout data or what?

Comment: @Rami thank you for response.according to the doc we should set title and image and other thing even we use custom view.if my notification was first in row, custom view show and if not, default title and image that set before show