# Android Notification Toolbar in the Status bar panel?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-notifications, android-statusbar

I was wondering how I could implement a fixed toolbar in the android Status bar of any android device. **I am talking about the buttons in the notification displayed below.** An example is provided below. Is it possible have this running even when the user hasn't opened the application?

Can someone point me in the right direction please? Is there a library or can we implement this using the native android libraries provided?

[image]

Comment: You can simply create an ongoing `Notification` with a custom `View` that is started in a boot Receiver. No need for a library.

Comment: Can you give me an example or a reference link please? :) @MikeM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple example, the following code will issue at boot an ongoing `Notification` with a `Button` to launch your app.

First, in your manifest, request the permission to get the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast, and register a Receiver to handle it.

```
<manifest ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    ...

    <application ...>
        ...

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The `BootReceiver` simply issues the `Notification` using a `static` method which is defined in `MainActivity` for this example.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MainActivity.setNotification(context, true);
    }
}
```

The `setNotification()` method creates a `RemoteViews` instance for the `Notification` using the simple layout below, and sets a `PendingIntent` on the `Button` with the launch `Intent` for your app.

```
public static void setNotification(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    NotificationManager manager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (enabled) {
        final RemoteViews rViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                                                   R.layout.notification);

        final Intent intent = context.getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());

        if (intent != null) {
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                                                         0,
                                                         intent,
                                                         0);

            rViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.notification_button_1, pi); 
        }

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
        builder.setContent(rViews)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(0)
            .setOngoing(true);

        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
    else {
        manager.cancel(0);
    }
}
```

The `Notification`'s layout is simply an `ImageView` and a `Button` in a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/notification_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/notification_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please note that, since API 3.1, you will have to launch your app at least once after installation to bring it out of the *stopped* state. Until then, the `BootReceiver` will not be delivered the broadcast.

Comment: Not as it is. I wasn't sure how you wanted to handle that, but all you need to do is call the `setNotification()` method with `true` as the second argument wherever you want to issue it. For example, if you want to show it when `MainActivity` starts, call the following line in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate()` method: `setNotification(this, true);`. Whenever you want to hide the `Notification`, call it with `false` as the second argument.

Comment: I took "when the user hasn't opened the application" to mean that you'd want it to show constantly, even if the user hasn't yet run your app during the current session. That's what the boot Receiver takes care of. If you install your app, run it once, then reboot, it'll show shortly after the boot process is done. It may take a little bit.

Comment: I ma not getting the notification when I launch the app :/ Is your code correct Mike?

Comment: Awesome solution mate, I think you solved my problem! Assuming that the user has run the app once before, Does this notification show up even after a restart?

Comment: If by restart you mean reboot, then yeah, that's what the Receiver is for. If you mean restarting the app, the `Notification` will stay there until you hide it. If you want it to show right when the user starts `MainActivity`, put a call in `onCreate()` like I describe in my first comment here. Also, calling that method with `false` will hide the `Notification`, whenever you want to get rid of it. An ongoing `Notification` has to be cancelled programmatically. You can't swipe it away.

Comment: Amazing! You solved my problem. I will accept this. Thanks mate :) One last clarification, I just changed my XML layout's structure and added a few buttons but the notification remains the same when I run it. The changes can't be seen. Do I need to uninstall it everytime to see the changes?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to uninstall before you update with a new build, but sometimes IDEs fail to update the XML in layouts if you change it. You might need to clean, then rebuild the project. Also, there is only a limited subset of `View`s that you can put in `Notification`s, so you have to use only those. Gimme a second, and I'll find the list for ya.

Comment: OMG, can the height of the notification be changed? Everything was crammed in to a single row

Comment: Yeah, have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237495/create-custom-big-notifications) for how to create large `Notification`s. It's just a matter of setting the `View` differently. And have a look at [this developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) for the list of `View`s you can use. It's under the "Creating the App Widget Layout" section. Ignore the fact that it's about App Widgets. They use the same `RemoteViews` as `Notification`s.

Comment: I'm facing an issue with setting up a custom XML for this solution. I posted another question for it. If you are free, can you have a look Mike? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952090/android-notification-bad-notification-posted-from-package-couldnt-expand-remo

Comment: You were right. 'View' was causing the issue. Fixed it :)

Comment: No problem. Yeah, I'm not sure exactly why they wouldn't allow that, but that's how it is.

Comment: don't forget to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml
android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: @MIKEPERETZ Third line in the very first code block in my answer.