# Get Android notification panel width

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-custom-view, remoteview

I'm creating some custom remoteViews, In order to draw custom views and layouts to a bitmap as wide as the notification panel I need its exact width.

As every vendor changes the width of the notification panel and in most cases it will changes based on orientation, It's difficult to find a regular pattern on that.

Is there any way to get its width?

[image]
[image]

The pink part is pure remoteViews and the bottom part is an imageview which I draw my custom view to it, since I don't have the parent width, all the child views get crumble together.

Comment: I am not aware of any API that offers this, and I would be skeptical about any hacks. For example, notifications on Chrome OS (raised by Android apps) go in the Chrome OS notifications area, which is somewhat different than the notification shade on ordinary Android environments.

Comment: i have the same problem

Comment: maybe you can share your code for this?

Comment: Please refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237495/create-custom-big-notifications

Comment: The smallest *android* phone screen *today* is [360dp wide](https://design.google.com/devices/) and the notification shade is [400dp wide on tablets](https://cdn2.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3586448/Android_Lollipop_notifications_bar.png). Why don't you just build one layout and rely on having just 360dp of available space?

Comment: so  have u solved this problem and how ?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use LinearLayout with  `android:orientation="horizontal"` and `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, and to put `android:layout_weight="1"` and `android:layout_width="0dp"` for every view in that layout. That means that every view in that layout will have same width. More about it you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html).

UPDATE: In [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6675721/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/system_bar_notification_panel.xml) it says that notification tray width is **478dp**.
So, try with that. Maybe some manufactures have different size, but this is good number to start with :).

Comment: i need exact width of panel in pixels :)

Comment: Why do you need exact width? It's never good idea to calculate size of views manually.

Comment: i need it for calculating the size of bitmap in my image download task @Vladimir

Comment: You can use fitCenter or cropInside on your ImageView for scaleType, and use approximation for image size (size of notification panel shouldn't be bigger than 300dp)

Comment: i know that , my problem is resizing large bitmaps that need exact size of the image view that is displaying that bitmap @Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get the width and calculate your custom layout

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Use the width to calculate your custom layout

Comment: I think, this code will provide maximum width and height of the screen available. Not Notification panel width.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355367/height-of-statusbar/3356263#3356263) will answer your question.

Comment: This is definitely not the size of the notifications. It will give wrong dimension for tablets. And there is guarantee for the future for this to be true either.