# Convert View to remoteview in Android

Tags: android, view, remoteview

is it possible to convert inflated view to remoteview?

```
View to RemoteViews
```

I wish to create View and add to notification that accepts only RemoteViews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. They are actually completely different.

`RemoteView` is where you define how to create that `View`. You cannot give it directly, it should now how to create it if it lose it.

I explained very similar thing here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27701965/1016462